# Low Internal Memory issue

Tags: android

I know this problem was discussed a thousand times but here's the topic number 1001. I was developing a game for android, testing it every time on a device (I can't use the emulator). Finally, I got the low internal memory message and was unable to test any further. Of course, at first I removed all unnecessary stuff, then some necessary but rarely used stuff, I cleared every cache I found, every file/program I could afford removing and so on. Right now I have very few apps installed (much less than I used too), about 130 MB free internal memory and 2 GB free internal sd card. My application is using "preferExternal" option in the manifest and my device's android version is 2.3.6. And I **STILL** can't install new versions of my app, even after removing the old one. I'm getting desperate. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i'm using cyanogemod 11. After installing the new rom, i got the message "not enough internal memory" and was not able to install any further app.

My solution: delete all files under /data/lost+found

How-to:

- start the terminal
- type su to get superuser rights
- go to lost+found: cd /data/lost+found
- rm -r * to delete all data in this dir